# Cosine Convolution Theorem

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, integral-transforms

I have found a number of sources that suggest:

$$\int_0^\infty f(t)g(t)\sin(xt) dt = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty f(s) \sin(ts) ds\right) \left(\int_0^\infty g(s)\sin(xs)\sin(ts)ds\right)dt$$

For example, here http://dsp-book.narod.ru/TAH/ch03.pdf, formula 3.3.22, where $$2\sin(xs)\sin(ts)=\cos((x-t)s)-\cos((x+t)s)$$

But this doesn't appear to work at all. Let $f(t)=g(t)=e^{-t}$, then according to mathematica: $$LHS = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{x}{4+x^2}$$ $$ RHS = \frac{i\pi}{2x(x-2i)}\ \ \ Im(x)<-1$$

How are these the same??? They don't appear similar at all. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Well at the very least, the LHS calculation is wrong, there is no out front factor. And the RHS calculation is wrong, as when you plug in $x=0$ into the right integral, it should be $0$.

Comment: According to mathematica, LHS is  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FourierSinTransform%5Be%5E%28-2t%29%2Ct%2Cx%5D

Comment: I agree with you the RHS is questionable, so why is mathematica giving me that answer..

Comment: Wolfram doesn't always do what you think you told it to do. [You didn't have the Fourier parameters option set to your transform convention so Mathematica use it's own default](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierParameters.html). Try integrating the expression directly and you will see Mathematica led you astray. Similarly, Mathematica doesn't behave well under composition of transforms if that's how you were coding it instead of using the integral function, which is why it gave you the other wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that a Fourier Transforms could have multiple answers. I guess that makes sense when crossing an abscissa, just wasn't paying attention; why would Mathematica default to Im<-1, instead of Reals. It appears I need to include the assumption that x is real. Also it appears I had worked out the wrong coefficient in the front.

```
Sqrt[2/ Pi]*
 Integrate[
  FourierSinTransform[Exp[-t], t, s]*
   FourierSinTransform[Exp[-t]*Sin[x*t], t, s], {s, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
```

and

```
FourierSinTransform[Exp[-2 t], t, x, 
 Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
```